# re.sub is showing unusual behaviour

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
value_list = ['oper-status','downward','upward','some','mid']
regex = r"\$\d+"
test_str = "Test Succeeded!! value is within the range of $1-$2 ,$3 $4 its value is {{post['x']}}"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)
i = 0
if len(value_list) > 1 :
  for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
        matchNum = matchNum + 1
        i = i + 1
        print ("{match}".format( match = match.group()))
        test_str = re.sub(regex,value_list[i],test_str,count=i)
   print test_str
```

and i am getting following output

```
$1  
$2
$3
$4
Test Succeeded!! value is within the range of downward-upward ,upward some its value is {{post['x']}}
```

while i was expecting

```
Test Succeeded!! value is within the range of downward-upward ,some mid its value is {{post['x']}}
```

what is problem with my code

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so how would i achieve my expected output if you can point out

Comment: You need to just use `re.sub` directly, no point iterating through the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Because You're using `count=i`, your string will be replaced like this:

`i=1` -> `"Test Succeeded!! value is within the range of downward-$2 ,$3 $4 its value is {{post['x']}}"`

`i=2` -> `"Test Succeeded!! value is within the range of downward-upward ,upward $4 its value is {{post['x']}}"`

`i=3` -> `"Test Succeeded!! value is within the range of downward-upward ,upward some its value is {{post['x']}}"`

You should use `count=1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `re.sub` directly with the `\$(\d+)` regex while accessing the replacement strings from the list by converting Group 1 value to `int` within a lambda expression:

```
import re
value_list = ['oper-status','downward','upward','some','mid']
regex = r"\$(\d+)"
test_str = "Test Succeeded!! value is within the range of $1-$2 ,$3 $4 its value is {{post['x']}}"
print re.sub(regex,lambda x: value_list[int(x.group(1))], test_str)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6amG3C).

This one pass regex replacement will help you avoid issues like you have with your original approach, namely, you replaced more times than necessary with `count=i`.

If there can be matches like `$12` (and the list has no 12 elements) add a condition:

```
print(re.sub(regex,lambda x: value_list[int(x.group(1))] if int(x.group(1)) < len(value_list) else x.group(), test_str))
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/afoq4U)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you assign `count=i` instead of `count=1` in `re.sub`

- at 1st iteration, i=1, $1 is replaced
- at 2nd iteration, i=2, $2 $3 is replaced
- at 3rd iteration, i=3, $4 is replaced
- at 4th iteration, i=4, nothing left to replaced

You could have done all this using [str.format](https://pyformat.info)

```
value_list = ['oper-status','downward','upward','some','mid']
test_str = "Test Succeeded!! value is within the range of {x[1]}-{x[2]} ,{x[3]} {x[4]} its value is {{post['x']}}".format(x=value_list)
# "Test Succeeded!! value is within the range of downward-upward ,some mid its value is {post['x']}"
```